# Mock `__setitem__ ` of a subclass of dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, pytest

I am trying to subclass a dict, and making sure that `__setitem__` is called when a new item is added.

I do know that `__setitem__` is called (if I add `1/0` I see it), but I cannot confirm it from my unit tests. I have this behaviour if I inherit from `dict` and `UserDict`.

What would be the right way to do it?

```py
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import MagicMock


class MyDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        # 1 / 0 # adding this confirms that my method is actually called
        super().__setitem__(key, value)


class TestAssumptions:
    def test_setitem_called1(self):
        t = MyDict()
        with mock.patch.object(t, "__setitem__", new=MagicMock(wraps=t.__setitem__)) as setitem:
            t["a"] = 1
            setitem.assert_called_once()  # Expected 'mock' to have been called once. Called 0 times.

    def test_setitem_called2(self):
        t = MyDict()
        t.__setitem__ = MagicMock(wraps=t.__setitem__)
        t["a"] = 1
        t.__setitem__.assert_called_once()  # Expected 'mock' to have been called once. Called 0 times.
```

This might not be something smart to do as is (test behaviour, not implementation as the first comment says), but:

- this is a minimal example, not real life
- not being able to do this means I do not get how patch/mock works. I want to fix this.
- the final goal is to compare different dict subclasses. It is "known" that, for instance, inheriting from `UserDict` has different behaviour that inheriting from `dict`. This is actually what I am trying to confirm or inform.

Comment: Test _behaviour_, not implementation. Right now `MyDict` would work just the same if you removed `__setdict__` entirely, and your tests should support that safe refactor.

Comment: @jonrsharpe athough correct in general, I edited the question to explain why this still is something I want to understand.

Comment: The more direct problem is you're trying to mock the method on the instance, but it's called on the class - `mock.patch.object(MyDict, "__setitem__")` would _pass_, at least, but that's a terrible test (it's testing _Python_, `t["a"] = 1` -> `t.__setitem__("a", 1)` isn't code you wrote). And you can't patch `dict`, to find out if _that_ implementation is delegated to; it's immutable. What _"different behaviour"_ are you actually trying to explore, this is likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thanks! It actually is exactly it: I am testing (my understanding of) python. Your help made me confirm that `__setitem__` is **not** called on `update()` if `MyDict` inherits from `dict`. I wanted to see that with my own eyes. It won't end up staying in my tests, but I am glad to have seen and understood it.